# Exporting SQL Server table to CSV issue commas, tabs and quotes

Tags: sql-server, excel, encoding, csv

After we export to flat file CSV, columns with commas, quotes and tabs cause problems in Excel. The vendor needs to read the file in Excel to make manual changes and then needs it in a flat file CSV format to load using PL/SQL into an Oracle table.

I have a few questions:

- I can remove those characters from the table in SQL Server, but is there a smarter way?
- Will saving the CSV file from Excel cause problems when attempting to load the file into Oracle?
- We need the first row to have column names. Is there any SQL way to generate all the files in one swoop (the titles in the first row) rather than using export to flat file?

Update: I'm attempting an MSSQL export to excel, but some tables give me an error of "Too many fields defined"

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a few options here.

1) Choose a different deliminator (one that is NOT in your output) ~ or ` or | might work

2) Wrap each output field in quotes, csv excel know to treat that as one field.

2a) if your output contains a " then you need to double them so CSV/Excel know that you mean a " instead of end or begining of a new field.

3) Don't use CSV for this reason, use XML.  Oracle handles it too..

4) make the import/Export position based instead of delineation

So direct responses to your question:

**but is there a smarter way?** Use XML, SQL server & Oracle both support and can import from it.

**does it make sense to save to csv when done in excel**
Not to me

**will that cuase problems when attempting to load the file into Oracle anyway**?
Unless you've handled all the special characters and escaped them properly with proper delineation, yes it could.

**any SQL way to generate all the files in one swoop (the the tiles in the first row) rather than using export to flat file?** again I suggest XML, or EDI.

Comment: The vendor specifically wants csv with the first row with column names. I'm not seeing an export to XML option from my sql 2005 client.

Comment: @cyberpine too bad the vendor doesn't accept XML as far as export from 2005... here's a [link](http://netrsc.blogspot.com/2008/01/export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-xml.html) and [another This is MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184(v=sql.90).aspx#bulk_export_xml_data) and [one more](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=23)...

Comment: @cyberpine What I would ask the vendor is how do they then need to receive the situations you listed.  comma's in data should be... escaped how?  if they say wrap the field in " then ask if you should double up " in data to escape them?(IE 2 and 2a)above

Comment: xQbert!  Thank you.. not sure why I did not think of that.. just escaping those and having the Vendor deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar challenge - exporting from SQL to Excel... while easy to do from query results, right-click and save results into a CSV.  The problem was any columns containing commas would disrupt the structure of the table.

I solved this using `OPENROWSET` and pumped the data directly into `Excel` file.  The most dummy-proof way I found to do this:  [SQL Server export to Excel with OPENROWSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909933/sqlserver-to-excel-export-with-openrowset)

Although I believe I used more recent versions of both Excel and MSSQL, here's my code:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test.xlsx', [Sheet1$])
select * from TestTable
```

Thanks!
Ken

Comment: I received a security error while trying to run this with my default SQL Server installation.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by preparing a SQL statement that produces the data you want. Have SQL replace any double-quote characters (`"`) with two double-quotes (`""`), e.g., `SELECT REPLACE(CAST(field1 as NVarchar(MAX)),'"','""') AS field1 FROM table1`.

- Right-click on the desired database within Object Explorer
- In the context menu, select Tasks->Export Data
- Source: Select `SQL Serve Native Client` (at end of list)
- Destination: Select `Flat file`
- Browse to select file, e.g. exported.csv

  - Check `Unicode`
  - Enter a single double-quote character for the `Text qualifier`: "
- Select radio bullet: Write a query to specify the data to transfer
- Paste your SQL code
- Click through to `Finish`
- Open the file with Notepad++

  - Menu: Encoding->Convert to UTF-8
  - Save file

The text qualifier is the quote character used around each field. If you select a csv file, it automatically sets up the line endings and column separator correctly.