# Pasting Large Amounts of Data to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a query that I run in SQL Server using Management Studio. The results are output to the grid that I then copy and paste to Excel sheet that gets saved in .csv format. I've never had any problem doing this before but this one particular query includes a column that contains a large chunk of HTML (several thousand char.). If I try to paste the entire query output into excel it can't handle that column and the sheet is unusable.

I have to paste everything else and then copy each of the rows individually that contain the HTML and double click the destination cell in Excel to enter in "edit mode". Is there any way around this?

I have tried: Output to text but no matter what I set the maximum column value to in SSMS it truncates the HTML column. I have tried output to file but the only file choice it gives me is Crystal Reports. Is there a way to either put Excel in edit mode globally so that I can paste the entire thing at once, or to tell SSMS (Express Version) to output to a .csv file?

ETA: I've tried right clicking on the grid results and saving as .csv but it still truncates the HTML column. Even though I have "Results to Text" option set at 8K chars. and non XML data set to over 64K in the results to grid option.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use openrowset to write the results directly to [Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909933/sqlserver-to-excel-export-with-openrowset?rq=1)

Comment: I'm unclear about how this has to do with programming....

Comment: Pete-nothing counts as programming but what? How about it's "Programming related" in that it is what to do with the results of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Remy pointed out, have you tried using `OPENROWSET`:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\template.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') 
select * from myTable
```

-- EDIT

Make sure you have Ad Hoc Distributed Queries enabled:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Good luck.

Comment: This might work, however right now I have a 64 bit version of Server and I get the errror: OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode. From what I understand from searching the web the only fix for this is to uninstall existing Office products and reinstall 64 bit versions? Don't think I'll have the time to do that anytime soon...

Comment: See edits -- sounds like a SQL Server configuration issue.  Good luck.

Comment: No that still doesn't fix it. I've found a lot of refrences to the issue, the only fix seems to be to uninstall the 32 bit versions of Office and reinstall. Apparently the 32 bit version of the Jet engine is installed with Office. At least from what I can gather. I did try to reconfigure but the error remains.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because as far as I can tell it should work, if not for the 32 bit / 64 bit issue.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the database in SSMS select "Tasks" and then  "Export Data ...". Set the SQLServer as a source and an Excel file as destination. On the next step choose "Write a query to specify ..." and paste your query. If you need to automate this you can use SSIS.
If you don't have SSMS or you don't want to go through the export wizard each time you can use a free tool. Download R-Tag Report Manager from [www.r-tag.com](http://www.r-tag.com) , add your query as a SQL Ad-hoc report and export it to excel.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS 2012 (not sure about earlier versions), you can right click on the results and select `Save Results As...` and then select `CSV` as your output file.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original post above about this. Even though the only options that should apply are set for much larger columns it truncates the data when I use this method.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you. I tried this and it works.

Here are the steps for reference.

1.Export SQL Results in CSV (4 million rows)

This is how to Export:

Select all the query results (million of rows), right click then select "Save Results As"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhNOA.png)

Next Save it in CSV file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMk5A.png)

2.Download the System (Executable file) from the link in the video description. The system will split the large amount of records from CSV file for you to able to save and open the file and transfer it to Excel file.