# Export from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel

I'm trying to do export from SQL Server 2008 to Excel with `order by` (through a query) inside and I get a syntax error.

Please tell what am I missing (I know for sure it's related to `ORDER BY` and it's something small):

```
CREATE TABLE `Z_STOCK_PARTNERS_2` (
`Date` DateTime,
`Partner` LongText,
`Weight` Double,
`TotalCost` Double,
`ProductGroupID` LongText
ORDER BY `ProductGroupID`
)
```

Comment: A table per se cannot be ordered - you can use `ORDER BY` only on `SELECT` commands from that table ....

Comment: There's no ORDER BY in a CREATE TABLE.  Are you trying to do a SELECT from an existing table?  You can use an ORDER BY there.  Your syntax also doesn't look like SQL Server.  Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), and [here for examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx).

Comment: Here's what I do: I use the export function of SQL, I choose destination which is a new excel file, therefore it's CREATE TABLE  in the query. Then I choose the VIEW I want to export and then I do EDIT SQL. I see this query already inside just without the ORDER BY. I actually get now as I'm writing it, that this is the query just for the creation of the table and not for the export itself... :)

Comment: You're trolling us right?

Comment: Nope.. me just got confused :) I'm searching now how to export via query

Comment: In SSMS right click your database -> Tasks -> Export Data -> Choose source data -> Choose destination data -> Write a query -> Use @FreshPrinceOfSO's query -> Edit mappings - make sure all the types are appropriate (as Excel is not identical to SS). Here's the magic Edit SQL button which shows the CREATE statement that bothers you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Date], [Partner], [Weight], [TotalCost], [ProductGroupID]
FROM Z_STOCK_PARTNERS_2
ORDER BY `ProductGroupID`
```

Comment: This is a regular select, I know this of course. The question is how to do it when exporting..

Comment: Use this select statment when using the wizard.

Comment: You can also look at using openrowset and skip the wizard entirely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909933/sqlserver-to-excel-export-with-openrowset